# OverlapBox more than I ask him

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character in whose face I create an overlapbox, I draw it through the gizmo, but for some reason it detects an object even before it enters its zone, which the gizmo draws. If i create overlapSphere then everything works fine

```c#
   private Vector3 overlapPos, overlapSize;
   private void Attack()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            var cam = Vector3.Scale(transform.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
            overlapPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1.2f, transform.position.z);
            overlapPos += cam*1.2f ;
            overlapSize = new Vector3(2.5f, 1.7f, 2f);
            Physics.SyncTransforms();
            var enemys = Physics.OverlapBox(overlapPos, overlapSize, transform.localRotation);
            foreach (Collider col in enemys)
                print(col.gameObject.name);
            //enemyGO.GetComponent<HealthComponent>().TakeDamage(10);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Attack();
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(overlapPos,transform.localRotation, overlapSize);
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(Vector3.zero, Vector3.one);
    }
```

Comment: This is [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Note that the second parameter of [`OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) is called **`halfExtends`**

> **Half** of the size of the box in each dimension.

So you rather want to either use half of the size for the overlapbox

```c#
Physics.OverlapBox(overlapPos, overlapSize * 0.5f, transform.localRotation);
```

or have to change the Gizmos in order to display the corrected double size

```c#
Gizmos.DrawWireCube(Vector3.zero, Vector3.one * 2);
```